# Ubuntu server 18.04 command to delete contents of sub-folders ever 6 months

Tags: server

I have a folder that contains many different sub folders and files in the sub folder

```
home/customer/main/a
home/customer/main/b
```

(each letter a through z is a random variable folder name example: house,media, etc ) i want to be able to clean the files in the folder after one of those files have reached 6 months of age but leave the folder system intact. and have this automatically run once a month

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you seek is what [logrotate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/logrotate.8.html) actually does. Added benefit: files can be compressed too. [Examples](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples), [more](https://www.linode.com/docs/uptime/logs/use-logrotate-to-manage-log-files/), and [more](https://serversforhackers.com/c/managing-logs-with-logrotate). So opt for that one since it is the standard in Linux.

- logrotate also understands the concept of months.

But if you want a command you can use

```
find /home/customer/main/ -mtime +183 -exec rm {} +
```

- 183 days is roughly 6 months (and on the safe side of 6 months) to keep it simple.
- You can add it to cron and have it run twice a year. You could use this: `30 03 01 Jan,Jul *` for the date arguments.